# get result from other controller of another application

Tags: rest, yii

Is it possible to get result from a controller that is on another application.

So I have a controller in application A, I want to get a result from another controller that is in application B.

Or maybe, a simpler question: how to make REST call between controllers of different application?

For example I want to get an ID at www.web2.com/index.php?r=controller2/action2
the caller controller is at www.web1.com.

Thank you

Comment: Simply expose another HTTP url at Controller B and user a HTTP request from Controller A to B with different parameters.

Comment: @chandpriyankara, can you please clarify your input?

Comment: Just like web services, you may easily create a http request to other controller. Since web service or other mechanism need further configurations, using http seems easy is my idea. But need to be careful with the required data rate, and to avoid dead locks in between calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use webservice to do so, see: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice